# Tensorflow model throwing not an element of this graph with Flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I have this class for finding the sentence embeddings for a given sentence

```
class Embeddings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.embedding_model_url = config_obj.tf_model_url
        self.embedding_model = hub.Module(self.embedding_model_url)
        self.messages = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
        self.output = self.embedding_model(self.messages)
        # self.initialize_graph()

    @staticmethod
    def initialize_graph():
        with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])

    def get_sentence_embeddings(self, sentence):

        with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
            result = session.run(self.output, feed_dict={self.messages: [sentence]})

        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence = "GoAir is waiving cancellation and change fees for Bhubaneswar, Kolkata and Ranchi flights for travel between May 2 and May 5, the airline said in a statement"
    tf_object = Embeddings()
    embeddings = tf_object.get_sentence_embeddings(sentence)
    print(embeddings)
```

This works as a stand alone application, but when I tried to integrate it with Flask like this

```
from sentence_embeddings import Embeddings

embedding_obj = Embeddings()
@app.route('/get-similar-claims', methods=['POST'])
def get_similar_claims():
    params = request.get_json()
    claim = params.get("claim", "")
    num_results = params.get("num_results", 10)
    t0 = time.time()
    # claim_embeddings = ""
    claim_embeddings = embedding_obj.get_sentence_embeddings(claim)
    logger.info("Time taken to calculate sentence embeddings - {}".format(round(time.time() - t0, 4)))
    return Response(json.dumps(claim_embeddings), mimetype='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5001)
```

It throws an error

```
File "/Users/anuragsharma/claim_similarity/api/app.py", line 32, in get_similar_claims
    claim_embeddings = embedding_obj.get_sentence_embeddings(claim)
  File "/Users/anuragsharma/claim_similarity/api/sentence_embeddings.py", line 31, in get_sentence_embeddings
    result = session.run(self.output, feed_dict={self.messages: tf.convert_to_tensor(sentence)})
  File "/Users/anuragsharma/anaconda3/envs/similarity-search/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/anuragsharma/anaconda3/envs/similarity-search/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1095, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?,), dtype=string) is not an element of this graph.
I0730 16:44:33.384036 123145584836608 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2019 16:44:33] "POST /get-similar-claims HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're losing context to the tf graph because of the threading in flask. When you load your model you need to save the reference to the tf graph so you can use it later.

```py
def __init__():
    self.model = load_model()
    self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()

def predict():
    with self.graph.as_default():
        self.model.predict()
```